# Vue data not defined within component, however it is

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm trying to do something very simple, however i'm having issues! I can see this being something simple I have over-looked however everything seems fine to me!

So I have got a component `m-input`, at the moment all i'm doing is adding list items based on a data property value.

```
<m-input>
    <div class="tabs">
        <ul>
            <li v-for="i in count"><a data-tab="address" v-html="'Address' + i">Address @{{ i }}</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</m-input>
```

This is the component, really simple right?

```
<template>
    <div>
        <slot></slot>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
    export default {
        props: [],
        data: function() {
            return {
                count: 3
            }
        },
        mounted() {},
        methods: {}
    }
</script>
```

As you can see i'm adding a data property `count`, however I get the following error:

> [Vue warn]: Property or method "count" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render.

What's the issue here? It looks fine to me!

Comment: `count` is expected on the parent instance in this case, not the `m-input` instance. You need to set the scope AFAIK. Looking for reference now.

Comment: I though that due to me referencing `count` within my component that it will be within the component scope?

Comment: No, take a look at: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-slots.html#Scoped-Slots

Comment: That documentation doesn't really explain how to define the scope to the component, this doesn't work: `<template slot-scope="this">`

Comment: Why do you want the count to be on the child component? It doesn't really make sense in this instance because you're defining the content on the parent level so the variable should also be controlled on the parent level.

Comment: The count is only for this component, I will have a button within the component to increase this number. The count doesn't really have anything to do with the entire app.

Comment: Ok, so why have the `<slot>` in that case? Why not just put the loop within the component? Think about the component being decoupled from the main app. It doesn't make sense to define the template outside of the component but use a variable from within the component. I'm not sure how to help other than these points because the way you're doing it doesn't fit what I'd expect to see. Sorry.

Comment: I want to be able to re-use this component, as the functionality will be useful in other places, but will have different HTML

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you need to expose a data property from a child component to the parent you can make use of [Scoped Slots](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-slots.html#Scoped-Slots) as  @webnoob rightly mentioned. In your child component you need to bind that data property in the slot ..

```
<template>
    <div>
        <slot :count="count"></slot>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
    export default {
        props: [],
        data: function() {
            return {
                count: 3
            }
        },
        mounted() {},
        methods: {}
    }
</script>
```

Then in the parent you can expose that property through the `slot-scope` attribute. Combined with `Object Destructuring` to simplify the syntax a bit ..

```
<m-input>
    <div class="tabs" slot-scope="{ count }">
        <ul>
            <li v-for="i in count"><a data-tab="address" v-html="'Address' + i">Address @{{ i }}</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</m-input>
```

Comment: This is the correct approach to sort the issue BUT I still think it's an odd approach...

Comment: @webnoob It's a common pattern although I do agree it requires some mind bending.

Comment: Ha, yes. Mind bending indeed :) Perhaps I'm too straight forward for it ;)